# How do you inspect your buffs?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I'm playing through Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls on PS4. I just started Adventure Mode, and I noticed a new icon above my health meter. It is a treasure chest, and hasn't gone down the entire time I've been playing Adventure Mode.

I can deduce that because of the mode I'm in, I'm getting a boost to my treasure find. However, I was wondering if there's a way to see what it actually gives me?

Most of the other buffs in that bar are spells I cast on myself, so I know what they can do, but I have noticed a few others from time to time that I'm not sure what they are.

[image: Diablo 3 screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an ongoing community event that actually ends today (Jan 23rd) and began on the 16th.

The treasure chest signifies a buff that was added to make it so that when one treasure goblin spawns on the map, another one spawns next to it (this was the buff for PS4,XBONE, and PC; for PS3,360 the event was 100% extra XP gain).

But to answer the real question, press the touch pad [##] to access your Inventory. If you accidentally press the wrong side and access your Skills just press L1 to navigate to Inventory. Once there, Press square to access the "Detailed Stats" page. On the right hand side you will see a window that shows all your current active buffs and what they do. If the list is very long, you can scroll through it with the Right Analog Stick.

Happy loot hunting.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I don't think I ever even noticed that you could hit square on that Inventory Screen.